# Rewriting a $ \sin x $ in terms of factors

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, functions

If a function $f$ has roots $a$, $b$, $c$ then the function can be written as
$$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\dotsc.$$
For example
$$h(x)=x^2-5x+6=(x-3)(x-2)\\g(x)=x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$$
So, $\sin$ has roots $n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
\begin{align}
\sin x
&=(x-0)(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x+3\pi)\dotsc\\
&= x(x^2-\pi^2)(x^2-4\pi^2)(x^2-9\pi^2)\dotsc\end{align}
Clearly, LHS and RHS are not equal.

What I am missing?

Comment: Is $e^{x}-1=(x-0)?$

Comment: You are rediscovering Euler's solution to the Basel problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler%27s_approach

Comment: Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product#Proof_using_Euler's_infinite_product_for_the_sine_function

Comment: @geetha290krm $e^2-1=(x-0)(x-a)(x-b)... \ Where\ a,b,c... must\ be\ complex\ roots\ of\ the\ function\ $

Comment: Also related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem

Comment: That product does not converge.

Comment: "If a function $f(x)$ has roots $a$, $b$, $c$ then function can be written as..."  No.  This is not true.  This is only true for *polynomial functions*.  And only up to some constant scaling factor.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of misconceptions in the original question.

1. In the original question, it is claimed that if $f$ has roots in a set $Z$ (I am using $Z$ for the set of zeros), then
   $$ f(x) = \prod_{z\in Z} (x-z). $$
   Strictly speaking, this is only kind of true for polynomials.  The relevant theorem is the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), which says that if $z$ is a root of a polynomial function $p$, then $(x-z)$ is a factor of $p(x)$.  This, combined with the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), implies that if $Z$ is a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) describing all of the roots of a polynomial function $p$, then
   $$ p(x) = C \prod_{z\in Z} (x-z)^{m(z)}, $$
   where $z$ is an element of $Z$ with multiplicity $m(z)$ and $C$ is some constant.

   But, to be clear, this is a result about **polynomials** (with roots in $\mathbb{C}$, though this part can be generalized a little), not about general functions.
2. The title of the question reads "Rewriting a $\sin x$ in terms of factors".  The notion of "factors" doesn't really make sense in this context.  By way of analogy, if $p$ and $d$ are *integers*, then we say that $d$ is a factor of $p$ if there is another integer $q$ such that $p = dq$ ($d$ is the divisor and $q$ the quotient).  The notion of factoring integers is kind of interesting, as most integers are not "units" (i.e. most integers don't have a multiplicative inverse which is also an integer).

   By contrast, factoring rational numbers or real numbers is rather uninteresting, because most of these numbers *are* invertible (the only exception is zero).  Hence if $p$ and $d$ are *any* real or rational number, then there exists a number $q$ such that $p=dq$.  Factoring is rather trivial.

   The world of general functions is similar.  If $f$ and $d$ are any almost any arbitrary functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with $d$, then it is possible to find a function $g$ such that
   $$ f(x) = d(x)g(x) $$
   for all $x$ (just define $g$ by
   $$ g(x) = f(x) / d(x).$$
   There is only a problem when $d(x) = 0$, which can be handled in a couple of ways:  either restrict the domains of $f$ and $g$ to the nonvanishing set of $d$, or only consider functions $d$ which never vanish.

   Either way, factoring is pretty boring, and it doesn't really make sense to talk about "the factors of $\sin$", as these factors are not really unique or canonical or distinguished in any meaningful sense.
3. It is often possible to rewrite a function as an infinite sum or product of terms.  For example, if a function is smooth (has continuous derivatives of all orders), then it is very likely that the function can be expressed as a Taylor series.  However, in any such case, it is important to known if and when that series or product representation converges.  In the case of the product suggested in the question, i.e.
   $$ \prod_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \left( x^2 - j^2 \pi^2 \right), $$
   the general term $x^2 - j^2 \pi^2$ has the property that
   $$ \lim_{j\to\infty} x^2 - j^2 \pi^2 = -\infty $$
   for *any* $x$.  The only values of $x$ for which
   $$ \left| \prod_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \left( x^2 - j^2 \pi^2 \right) \right| $$
   does not blow up are $ x\in \{j\pi : j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$—for these values, the product is zero (which, in the world of infinite products, means that the product "diverges to zero"; there are technical reasons why this is a reasonable sentence).

   This divergence is readily apparent—just try graphing the first several partial products, and note that they vary widely.  For example, I've [plotted the first three partial products using GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/nzgvjad9):

   [image]

   This is bad news.

This does not mean that all hope is lost, just that one needs to be a lot more careful about how the problem is approached.  The relevant theorem here is the [Weierstrass Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), which says that every *entire* function (there are a number of characterizations of "entire functions", but "complex differentiable at every point in the complex plane" is good enough for us) can be represented by some kind of (possibly infinite) product involving it's roots.

Note that the theorem does *not* assert that an entire function can be written as a product of terms of the form $(z-\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a root of the function.  The general terms in the product are actually quite a bit more complicated, and involve the complex exponential function.  The fact that
$$\sin(z) = \pi z \prod_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} \left( 1 - \frac{z^2}{j^2} \right), $$
where the general term is the product is kind of like $(z - \omega)$ for $\omega$ a root of $\sin(\pi z)$, is kind of a happy coincidence which results from the fact that the complex sine function is very closely related to the complex exponential function.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ can be written as $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)$ where $\{a_i:1\leq i \leq n\}$ are roots of $f(x)$ only when $f$ is a polynomial function... and for non polynomial functions, this doesn't works... suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)=1$, if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q^c}$... How can you write it as factors?... even a question like this doesn't makes sense...

So writing like this $\big( f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)\big)$ where $\{a_i:1\leq i \leq n\}$)are roots of $f(x)$ is only applicable for polynomial functions, and hence writing a Transcendental function like $\sin$ as this is not correct.

This is because, when given all roots of the polynomial, we somehow can determine the whole polynomial, and where the image for all other values for a polynomial function also depends on this... but this is not the case in general... There can be many many non polynomials functions whose values are zero at a given specific points... so it does not distinguish between other functions except at the zero points... writing like this will not be of much use... but the case is different with polynomial functions...

for example define, $g(x)=0,$ whenever $sin(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $\sin(x)\neq 0$, now if we try to represent like you did.. both $g(x)$ and $\sin(x) $ functions will have the same representation... but both of them are completely different functions...

Comment: You are missing a constant at the front.  The factors give you the roots; the constant then scales the curve.

Comment: @OM That is an *infinite* product.  When dealing with infinite sums or products, you have to worry about convergence.  The product you have proposed does not converge, while the one you've just quoted does.